# Sql query checking condition before insert row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `dbo.Tbl_ActivityInformations` and the data look like

```
Activityid  activitymaxcount   Activityusedcount
   1               10                 9
   2               10                 7
   3               15                15
```

And another table called `Tbl_AttendeeInformations` and the data look like

```
AttendedID    AssID     ActivityID
    13        123456      1,2
    14        123457      1,3
```

In the `Tbl_AttendeeInformations` table data will be inserted as new row from page and in the `ActivityInformations` table `Activityusedcount` column incremented by one for appropriate `activityID`.

Now I want to check before inserting a row into `AttendeeInformations` that `Activityusedcount < activitymaxcount` using `ActivityID`. If the condition is satisfied then only it will allow to insert otherwise it should rollback. I have function named `SplitString` to split `ActivityID` in `Tbl_AttendeeInformations`.

This is the code for `SplitString`

```
create  FUNCTION dbo.SplitString(@FormattedString varchar(8000),@Delimitter char(1))      
returns @retResults TABLE(Value varchar(8000),Rownumber int)      
as      
BEGIN      
        DECLARE        @SearchString as varchar(8000)      
        DECLARE        @AssignString as varchar(8000)      
        DECLARE @Index int                      
        DECLARE @Count int      

        set @SearchString = @FormattedString      
        set @AssignString= ''      
        set @Count = 0      

        while(len(@SearchString) > 0 )      
        begin                      
                SET @Index =   CHARINDEX(@Delimitter,@SearchString, 0)                      
                set @Count = @Count + 1      
                if  @Index = 0      
                begin      
                        INSERT INTO @retResults      
                                values( @SearchString,@Count)      
                        set @SearchString = ''      
                        continue      
                end                      
                set @AssignString = SUBSTRING(@SearchString,1, @Index - 1 )      
                INSERT INTO @retResults values      
                        (@AssignString,@Count)      

                SET @SearchString = (select SUBSTRING(@SearchString, @Index + 1, LEN(@SearchString) -  @Index ))      


        end      
        return      
END
```

Please do help.

Comment: You should **normalize** your tables properly - having `1,2` in a single column clearly violates even the first normal form - and this will make it really hard and messy to do even the most basic relational operations...

Comment: Unhappy that I can't upvote @marc_s's comment ten times. XX-delimited column values that break first normal form are horrible; having them in your key columns is completely unacceptable. (Yes, I **know** you didn't design it, I **know** you can't change it... but you have to draw a line somewhere!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode to show an idea:

```sql
INSERT INTO AttendeeInformations
SELECT act.*
FROM ActivityInformations act 
INNER JOIN AttendeeInformations at ON act.ActivityID = at.ActivityID
WHERE act.Activityusedcount < act.activitymaxcount
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but here we getting combined(1,2) activityids in AttendeeInformations

Comment: See updated answer, you can yourself decide which info to select, use act.* to select all/smth specific from ActivityInformations

Comment: Yes, i have seen but  the activityId are combined means (1,2) in AttendeeInformations table and in ActivityInformations indivisibly.So how can write inner join with out split

Comment: You can remove JOIN if you do not need to join second table, I'm not sure whether I got what are you trying to achieve